# ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

What might be the reason for getting the following error while deploying my Nodejs code to google cloud?

ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).

Comment: I have the exact same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665368/google-app-engine-node-js-application-unhealthy

Comment: There isn't any one cause, but as the error states it could be related to bad code. If @Sauron 's answer doesn't help you might try pushing incremental changes to your app to try and isolate the problem.

Comment: @Adam, the reason for the failure was inaccurate GCM registration id to the server id. So bad code...

Comment: got anthing or not ??, actually can you please tell me using app engine where are you going to put your routes files can you please have a look at my question may be you know anything about it ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975151/how-to-deploy-my-whole-app-on-app-engine-for-using-node-js-mongodb-redis-and-e

Answer (score 2):

There's no one cause for this error, as Adam mentioned.

You'll need to check the logs on the instances themselves, or SSH into them and see what's happening, or check the VM Builder logs, to which a link will be provided when you run the deploy command, and which you can also find in the Logs Viewer by selecting "Container Builder" as the resource to view logs for (usual default is "App Engine").

A common cause is not implementing a 200-response handler for `/_ah/health`, but there are any number of other root causes. It could even simply be that it's taking a long time for the instance to come up, for various reasons, and it's perfectly healthy - the deploy command just gave up on polling its status.

Comment: A good topic for documentation :) http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-app-engine/topics