# Google App Engine Node.js Application Unhealthy

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, timeout

I am attempting to test a fairly straightforward node.js app on google app engine. As seen below, all it is intended to do is listen to a change in a Firebase database, and subsequently send a GCM message to a user:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

// Create a reference to the push notification queue
var ref = new Firebase("firebaseDB");

var message = new gcm.Message();

var regTokens = ['A user GCM reg token'];

// Set up the sender with you API key
var sender = new gcm.Sender('GCM sender ID');

message.addData('syncNewData', 'Hello Member!');

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {

    // Now the sender can be used to send messages
    sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: regTokens }, function (err, response) {
        if(err) console.error(err);
        else    console.log(response);
    });

  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

However, every time I attempt to deploy to the app engine, the process runs smoothly until `Updating module [default].../`, running for several minutes, whereby the error appears:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting
VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still
 deploying).
```

I am fairly new to node.js as well as appengine, but I am simply attempting to test to ensure all components work together.

Why would this error exist?

Comment: Launched the app on local...turns out the GCM regid from my device linked to my old server was not in sync with the new GCM server id, therefore was throwing errors...Simply re-registered my mobile device and copied the GCM reg id into the code above, everything is working fine on local.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This almost always means you have a crash during app startup when running in App Engine.  We're not very good at surfacing these kinds of crashes today during deployment (working on that).  To see what's going on:

1. Go to the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. Click on cloud logging

[image: cloud logging]

3. Look for a `crash.log` or `stderr`:

[image: crash.log]

That's where you'll usually find the problem.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it was the issue.

Comment: Wow, this was very hard to guess.