# How does Node.JS in App Engine Standard handle crashes?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

When a function in node crashes, it tends to bring down the entire app. This is mitigated by solutions like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) and/or having global listeners for uncaught exceptions.

How is this handled in AppEngine *Standard* NodeJS? If an uncaught exception happens - are they automatically recovered (and logged) - allowing other functions still able to run, or must some manual work be done to handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Node.js app crashes, AppEngine will log it's errors in its Logging mechanism and will restart. If it keeps crashing, it will mark the application as unhealthy:

[Google App Engine Node.js Application Unhealthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665368/google-app-engine-node-js-application-unhealthy)

If you don't want to depend on AppEngine, you can always add this code snippet to all your Node.js apps:

```
const someFn = // do something to handle exceptions
process.on("unhandledRejection", someFn );
```

Although I would advise against it.

For me, personally, I prefer having my machine in Google Cloud ( no AppEngine ) and have a server for me where I can have PM2 and where I can spice it how I want, but if you are invested in AppEngine, this is the best you can do.

Another thing you need to keep in mind is that even though GAE logs errors, **you do have a log limit**, so if your application is crashing all the time, you will eventually hit it.

Also, using Monads in your code ( *cough cough* Sanctuary / Folktale ) that force you to deal with exceptions also helps :P

Comment: Thanks @Flame_Phoenix ... nice to see you here :D - the article you linked to is talking about AppEngine Flexible which doesn't have any wrappers and is almost like a compute instance... I believe Standard might be different in this regard

Comment: While I was unable to find any document that specifically addresses this issue with Node, I am fairly certain of the behavior. Still, if you are using GAE you have a limited amount of support requests you can create, and you can use them to send this question to GAE support teams.

Comment: Seems the Bronze tier doesn't provide any support requests :\

Comment: Are you in Trial? If you are, you have the right to a support ticket.

Comment: This docs link can be useful - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed

Comment: Although I couldn't find any documentation to back it up, it's true that unhandled errors will be logged and the application will be restarted, which will also be recorded in the log as an /_ah/stop request.

Comment: Anyone have any fresh updates here for app engine standard, @davidkomer? We're getting instances dieing off left and right because of some small error and it takes down all of our instances, it's a royal pain. So outside of writing bug free code, what other options do we have?

Comment: We had one of our instances crash and there were no logs, nothing..